# Google Places Callback not being called in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, sdk

I am using the GoogleMaps SDK (maps & places). For some reason the following callback is not being called. I have put loggers in there but nothing happens.

```
var placesClient : GMSPlacesClient?

...


func run(){
    self.placesClient?.currentPlaceWithCallback({ (list: GMSPlaceLikelihoodList?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
       if let error = error {
           println("error: \(error.description)")
           return
       }

       if let list = list {
           self.renderList(list)
       }
    })
}
```

For some reason the block in **currentPlaceWithCallback** does not get called. Yesterday it happened because my API had a wrong bundle identifier, after changing which it started working. But today it stopped.

Any idea why this would happen ? Also, are we exposed to any API logs by Google ?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue on my iPhone 6 device AND iPhone 6 simulator.

1. **The fix** was to add the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` permission in Info.plist! But, it worked only on my iPhone 6 device, NOT the simulator.

   As mentioned in the Google Place Guide: 
   (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start)

   *Please note, as this sample requires access to the location of the device to get the current location, you will need to set the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with appropriate explanatory text in your project's Info.plist file. For more details, see the guide to getting current place.*
2. Now, the way I got it working on the **iPhone simulator was by changing my location on the Simulator: Debug -> Location**. That is, it was set to 'Apple' by default, I just changed it to Bicycle Ride.

It worked for me, may not for all.